Is this logic in Settings.py regarding database redunant
In the settings of a Django project I am working on this is the way the DATABASES has been set up. The person who has written this has explained that the if statement is a redundancy which doesn't make sense to me. As far as my understanding goes if the try fails that the if will also fail because they are setting 'default' the same way? Is this if statement redundant:
try:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': env.db(),
    }
except environ.ImproperlyConfigured:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
        }
    }

# Override with DATABASE_URL if it exists
if env('DATABASE_URL', default=None):
    DATABASES['default'] = env.db()

And if not can someone please explain to me to me why?
Thanks for any clarification.
I have tried using an empty value for DATABASE_URL but it doesn't seem to make a difference whether the if is there or not.
Please don't give me the same answer as ChatGPT either becauses after two questions I have it saying that it is redundant.

Hi Sean! Do you still need help concerning this? If not, choose an answer to mark this question as answered. Also welcome to [so].

The if block is redundant because:
If the try block doesn’t throw, [1] the env.db() values will be used successfully hence repeating the same invocation of env.db() in the if block is redundant.
If it throws, the exception is handled gracefully in the except block and an alternative is used. Making another invocation to env.db() [2] which just threw the handled exception will raise another exception that is not handled.

[1] The assumption is that invoking env.db() might throw exceptions.
[2] The assumption is that env('DATABASE_URL', default=None) allowed another invocation of env.db() which doesn’t seem likely but was assumed for educational purposes.

Thanks for the explanation that was my thought process too! I thought I might have been missing something.

Let us break down your code line by line:
try:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': env.db(),
    }
except environ.ImproperlyConfigured:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
        }
    }

If env.db() fails it will be backed up by sqlite3 database, if not then 'default' would be set to env.db() return, which is a str of database url.
Your database setup may fail and exception will be raised but then your code will stop executing and will show you a traceback.
At the point where you have if env('DATABASE_URL', default=None): this environment variable has been already checked and if it exists it has been already set up as your 'database'.
TL;DR: You are right. You can freely remove your if statement as redundant

Thank you :) I thought I was missing something extra but this is what I thought. Thanks for clearing it up.
